# dns server ip address is not written into resolv.conf

Tags: linux, bridge

linux mint 17.3

i have to manually write "nameserver 8.8.8.8" in /etc/resolv.conf on every reboot, it also gets stuck with message "waiting for network" where i press "ESC" button to skip that and manually "ifup br0" to bring up the bridge.

my option : `"echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf "  in /etc/rc.local file"` whats the other workaround? for bridge and nameserver on boot. below is my /etc/network/interfaces file

```
# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#10.0.2.193  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 10.0.2.199
        netmask 255.255.254.0
        gateway 10.0.2.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
#set static route for LAN
        post-up route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0  gw 192.168.0.1 dev br0
        bridge_ports eth1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

Comment: I would guess that your network config is being rejected on boot. I'm not overly familiar with configuring bridges, however your `bridge_ports` line only lists 1 interface. You are also trying to add a static route with a next hop IP which isn't in the same subnet as your br0 interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary reason the DNS configuration is failing is because you're using the [wrong keyword](https://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=resolvconf). Instead of `dns-nameservers` use `dns-nameserver`.

While you're there, you should probably fix the `post-up` line. As explained by @MarkoPolo in the comments,

> You are also trying to add a static route with a next hop IP which isn't in the same subnet as your br0 interface

This isn't a fatal error as would be considered by the `up` keyword, but it simply won't work. Are you trying to run two subnets on the same NIC?

Answer (score 0):

If yours `/etc/network/interfaces` is being rewrited on boot it means it's usually link into `/run` directory.

- 1) Set up correctly networking manager
- 2) Remove networking manager and make it a file.